# Select several levels of childs

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity Framework 6.
On my database I have these tables :

```
MasterTable ( Id , name)
    Child1 ( ID , name , vl1 , Master_ID)
    Child2 ( ID , name , vl2 , MasterID )
    Child3 (ID , name , vl3 , Master_ID )
        Child3Itm ( ID , name , Child3_ID)
```

For a given `MasterTable` item, I want to load with a single Query from database:

- All `Child1` where `vl1 > 5`
- All `Child2` where `vl2 > 6`
- All `Child3` where `vl3 > 7`

And in each `Child3` to load all of the `Child3Itm` content.

I'm using this query:

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MasterTable.Where(Function(t1) t1.id = 7)
                 Select New With {
                                   t,
                                   .chld1 = t.child1s.Where(Function(t21) t21.vl1 >5),
                                   .chld2 = t.child2s.Where(Function(t31) t31.vl2>6 ),
                                   .chld3 = t.child3s.Where(Function(t41) t41.vl3>7).Select(Function(t411) t411.Child3Itms)
                                  }).ToList
```

The problem is that no `Child3` are selected. All others are OK. What can i do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MasterTable.Where(Function(t1) t1.id = 7)
              Select New With {
                           t,
                           .chld1 = t.child1s.Where(Function(t21) t21.vl1 >5),
                           .chld2 = t.child2s.Where(Function(t31) t31.vl2>6 ),
                           .chld3 = (From t2 in t.child3s.Where(Function(t41) t41.vl3>7) 
                                Select New With {
                                           t2,
                                           .chld3it=t2.Child3Itms   
                                                 })
                               }).ToList
```

This is working too.
If someone can tell me if this answer is better or no compared with the other solution posted by antoni ???

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, it will be tough to diagnose. But since you have access to a debugger, you can do it yourself. With the code below, step over each line and inspect the variables. It should be easy to see where your code is failing

```
Dim masters = From t In context.MasterTable Where t = 7
Dim child1s = From m In masters Where m.child1s.vl1 > 5
Dim child2s = From m In masters Where m.child2s.vl2 > 6
Dim child3s = From m In masters Where m.child3s.vl3 > 7
Dim child3i = child3s.Child3Itms
```

Might be a typo in your question. Make sure the condition for the child3s is correct:

```
t41.vl>7
```

Should it be this?

```
t41.vl3 > 7
```

Comment: I want to read all the data described above with a single query. If i use your queries and read each collection with its own query , everything is ok.

Comment: no , it;s not a typo , everything is wrote correctly.

Comment: According to your table, child3 doesn't define vl, only vl3. So something is wrong

Comment: I wrote incorrectly in my post , i've corrected. It's vl3. But on my program i have all typed correctly.

Comment: if i remove the part .Select(Function(t411) t411.Child3Itms from my query , the child3 is filled correctly , but of course Child3itm is empty.

Comment: The Select will *transform* the Child3 into Child3Itm. So there won't be any Child3 returned, only Child3Itm. If they don't join in your database it won't return anything. We'd need to see your data, and make sure the schema has the keys linked.

Comment: So, can you run a corresponding SQL query which returns the Child3Itms?

Comment: Yes , not only a sql query but also a entity framework query like (From t in context.child3s where t.vl3>7 select t).Include("Child3itms") , and this query return the data from database.

Comment: Start combining my lines and see where it breaks

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lst = (From t In context.MasterTable.Where(Function(t1) t1.id = 7)
             Select New With {
                               t,
                               .chld1 = t.child1s.Where(Function(t21) t21.vl1 >5),
                               .chld2 = t.child2s.Where(Function(t31) t31.vl2>6 ),
                               .chld3 = t.child3s.Where(Function(t41) t41.vl3>7),
                               .chld3itms = t.child3s.Where(Function(t51) t51.vl3>7).Select(Function(t511) t511.Child3Itms)
                              }).ToList
```

Comment: Yes , this is working , but is this query correct , because as i can see one part of the query is repeated 2 times  t.child3s.Where(Function(t41) t41.vl3>7)????!!!